# Calculating combinations from categories

Tags: algorithms

I'm trying to calculate every possible selection from different categories.  1 choice must be made from every category and the categories are always in the same order.  I save a string where each character is the number of that choice from that category.  I have solved this with recursion and it works well when there are thousands of possibilities but is too slow when there are millions.  I'd like to change it to looping to hopefully speed it up.  Here is my recursive function (C#):

```
private void GetPartNumberPermutations(IList<int> choices, string partNumber)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < choices[0]; i++)
    {
        if (choices.Count > 1)
            GetPartNumberPermutations(choices.Skip(1).ToList(), partNumber + i.ToString());
        else
        {
            //add partNumber to the list
        }
    }
}
```

Choices is a list of the number of choices for each category and might look like { 2, 4, 5, 8, 2, 4 }.  Let's ignore the problem when one of the entries is > 9.

My final list of partNumbers comes out to:
000000
000001
000002
000003
000010
000011
000012
000013
000100
000101
etc

Comment: The recursion is not your bottleneck, `choices.Skip(1).ToList()` is. (1) you potentially recalculate the tail of the list multiple times. (2) you create a copy. Instead, pass the original list and an index where to start: `getPermutations(IList<int> choices, int start, string partNumber) { for int(i = start; ... }`

Comment: I'm sure that made a difference but after the change I realized my real bottleneck was adding the partNumber to the list (DB insert).  If I removed that, I created 136 million part numbers in 4 minutes when I was doing 3,000 a minute with the insert added in.  I'm going to have to work on that part.